# Identify the characters in this Doctor Who webcomic panel

Tags: doctor-who, character-identification, fan-fiction, webcomics

[image: In Print Group Image]

This image is a product of [In Print](http://www.inprintcomic.com/), a Doctor Who webcomic covering matters from throughout the franchise and into its most obscure offshoots. Can you identify these characters?

Comment: I would request that someone more skilled with imaging software than I am make a copy of the image with numbers over the characters for easy matching, and post it as the start of a community wiki answer.

Comment: I recognize the Doctor, the Doctor, the Doctor, and ... is that the Doctor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the absence of an annotated picture, I am going to proceed upwards, by rows, in a zig-zag fashion (for reasons that become obvious given the row #1 to row #2 transition) starting from the bottom-right-hand corner.  And *Hurt counts, damnit!*  ☺

<sup>*I, [Martha](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/348/martha), added this annotated picture and tried to put in the correspondences (in parentheses).*</sup>
[image: Annotated picture]

## Row #0, from right

1. <sup>(13)</sup> [Handles](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/07/in-print-episode-76.html) (cyberman head)
2. <sup>(10)</sup> [Frobisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobisher_(Doctor_Who))
3. <sup>(4)</sup> K9 (Mark 3?)

## Row #1, from left

1. <sup>(1)</sup> [First Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2017/07/the-gallifrey-exchange-2.html) (Hartnell)
2. <sup>(2)</sup> Second Doctor (Troughton)
3. <sup>(3)</sup> Third Doctor (Pertwee)
4. <sup>(5)</sup> Fourth Doctor (Baker)
5. <sup>(6)</sup> Fifth Doctor (Davison)
6. <sup>(7)</sup> [The Valeyard](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/04/paul-salvi-guest-strip-2.html) [wearing a wig and pretending to be](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/07/infinity-doctors-strip-3-jesse-lax.html) the Sixth Doctor (Baker)
7. <sup>(8)</sup> Seventh Doctor (McCoy)
8. <sup>(9)</sup> Eighth Doctor (McGann)
9. <sup>(11)</sup> "[the real, official](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/03/the-infinites-strip-24.html)" Ninth Doctor a.k.a. War Doctor (Hurt)
10. <sup>(12)</sup> Tenth Doctor (Eccleston)

## Row 2, from right

1. <sup>(14)</sup> Eleventh Doctor (Tennant)
2. <sup>(15)</sup> [Adipose](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/04/in-print-episode-11.html) (*Partners in Crime*) (identified by [Discovery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931/discovery))
3. <sup>(16)</sup> [Meta-Crisis Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2016/05/in-print-104.html) (Tennant)
4. <sup>(17)</sup> Twelfth Doctor (Smith)
5. <sup>(18)</sup> [Thirteenth Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2017/10/in-print-120.html) (Capaldi)
6. <sup>(19)</sup> [Bernice Summerfield](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2017/10/in-print-120.html), [an archaeologist from the future who hangs around with the Seventh Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2017/08/in-print-115.html) and who secretly [dated the Eighth Doctor inside the Seventh Doctor's *Adventures*](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/04/in-print-episode-6.html)
7. <sup>(20)</sup> River Song, [an archaeologist from the future who now dates the Eighth Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2017/08/in-print-115.html)
8. <sup>(21)</sup> [Strax](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2017/04/in-print-112.html)
9. <sup>(22)</sup> [Alpha Centauri](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/02/in-print-episode-69.html) (identified by [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31051/jason-baker))
10. <sup>(23)</sup> [Nth Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/01/the-infinites-strip-34.html) (Briggs)
11. <sup>(24)</sup> [Mrs T.](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/05/in-print-episode-26.html) (per [the cast list](http://www.inprintcomic.com/p/cast.html))

## Row #3, from left

1. <sup>(25)</sup> [Martha](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/05/in-print-whovian-nature-part-3.html)
2. <sup>(26)</sup> Nardole
3. <sup>(31)</sup> [The Master](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/10/in-print-episode-37.html) (Roberts)
4. <sup>(33)</sup> The Master (Pratt)
5. <sup>(37)</sup> [House of Lungbarrow](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/10/in-print-97.html)
6. <sup>(41)</sup> [House of Lungbarrow](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/10/in-print-97.html)

## Row #4, from right

1. <sup>(39)</sup> ["Daughter", Family of Blood](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/04/in-print-human-nature-cover.html) (identified by [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31051/jason-baker))
2. <sup>(35)</sup> Eleventh Doctor (Tennant) in Human form as John Smith, Headmaster
3. <sup>(34)</sup> Seventh Doctor (McCoy) [as the same headmaster](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/05/in-print-not-human-nature-part-2.html)
4. <sup>(32)</sup> [The Master](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/09/in-print-episode-34.html) (*Survival*)
5. <sup>(30)</sup> The Master (Delgado)
6. <sup>(29)</sup> [Missy](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/10/in-print-96.html) (Gomez)
7. <sup>(28)</sup> The Master (Simm)
8. <sup>(27)</sup> [Mister Clever](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2016/12/the-dressing-room-part-1-jim-wilkins.html), the Twelfth Doctor (Smith) as the Cyber Planner (*Nightmare in Silver*)

## Row #5, from left

1. <sup>(54)</sup> [Movellan from *Destiny of The Daleks*](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2013/09/the-prop-cupboard-of-obscure-doom-6.html) (identified by [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31051/jason-baker))
2. <sup>(52)</sup> [Kroton](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2013/03/in-print-episode-44.html)
3. <sup>(36)</sup> "Son", Family of Blood (identified by [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31051/jason-baker))
4. <sup>(38)</sup> "Father", Family of Blood (identified by [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31051/jason-baker))

## Row #6, from right

1. <sup>(40)</sup> [Paul Cornell](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/12/goatees-and-eye-patches-page-13.html)
2. <sup>(44)</sup> Dalek
3. <sup>(53)</sup> Jack Harkness
4. <sup>(48)</sup> [Cyberman Brigadier Lethbridge-Stewart](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/11/in-print-curation-part-5.html)
5. <sup>(51)</sup> [Whisper Man](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/10/in-print-whisper-men.html) (identified by [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31051/jason-baker))

At this point, the rows get a little muddled, and an annotated picture is really needed.  So the rest from left to right somewhat haphazardly.

## The kids in the back row:

1. <sup>(55)</sup> [Bertie Bassett](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/04/in-print-episode-11.html) a.k.a. Kandyman (identified by [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31051/jason-baker))
2. <sup>(56)</sup> AI backup copy head of [The Master](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/11/in-print-episode-38.html) (Ainley), a.k.a. [The Shalka Master](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2013/07/the-infinites-strip-10.html)'s head
3. <sup>(57)</sup> [Clara](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/10/in-print-listen.html)
4. <sup>(58)</sup> [Dorium Maldovar](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2017/02/the-gallifrey-exchange-3.html) (identified by [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31051/jason-baker))
5. <sup>(59)</sup> [Fourth Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/12/in-print-curation-part-8.html) (identified by [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31051/jason-baker))
6. <sup>(60)</sup> [Madam Vastra](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/09/in-print-episode-35.html)
7. <sup>(61)</sup> George Litefoot (*The Talons of Weng Chiang*, *Jago & Litefoot*) (identified by [Jules](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/18944/jules))
8. <sup>(62)</sup> [The Other](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/02/in-print-episode-69.html) by Paul Hanley (identified by [Machavity](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/62709/machavity))
9. <sup>(63)</sup> Henry Gordon Jago (*The Talons of Weng Chiang*, *Jago & Litefoot*) (identified by [Jules](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/18944/jules))
10. <sup>(64)</sup> [Sherlock](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2012/05/in-print-episode-26.html) (Cumberbatch)
11. <sup>(65)</sup> [Doctor Watson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYaYM.jpg) (Freeman)
12. <sup>(50)</sup> [Third Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2017/10/in-print-120.html) ([Unbound](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2013/07/the-infinites-strip-10.html), Warner)
13. <sup>(66)</sup> [Snowman](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/03/the-infinites-strip-38.html) (*The Snowmen*)
14. <sup>(49)</sup> [Evil Eleventh Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2016/12/the-dressing-room-part-1-jim-wilkins.html) (Tennant) with a "rubbish beard"
15. <sup>(67)</sup> [The Great Intelligence](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/03/the-infinites-strip-38.html)
16. <sup>(68)</sup> [Ninth Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2013/01/the-infinites-strip-0.html) (Atkinson, *The Curse of Fatal Death*)
17. <sup>(69)</sup> [un-named Time Lord who answers the 'phone for the War Council of Gallifrey](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2017/07/the-gallifrey-exchange-2.html)
18. <sup>(47)</sup> [Alternative Continuity Eighth Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2013/07/in-print-episode-51.html)
19. <sup>(70)</sup> one of [The Eight Pre-Hartnell Incarnations](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/02/in-print-episode-68.html)
20. <sup>(46)</sup> [Doctor Who](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/11/in-print-98.html) (Cushing)
21. <sup>(71)</sup> one of [The Eight Pre-Hartnell Incarnations](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/02/in-print-episode-68.html)
22. <sup>(72)</sup> [Marvin](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2013/01/in-print-episode-42.html) from the *HHGTTG* TV series
23. <sup>(45)</sup> [The Shalka Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalka_Doctor) a.k.a. [Ninth Doctor](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2015/03/the-infinites-strip-38.html) (Grant)
24. <sup>(73)</sup> one of [The Eight Pre-Hartnell Incarnations](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/02/in-print-episode-68.html)
25. <sup>(74)</sup> one of [The Eight Pre-Hartnell Incarnations](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/02/in-print-episode-68.html)
26. <sup>(43)</sup> one of [The Eight Pre-Hartnell Incarnations](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/02/in-print-episode-68.html)
27. <sup>(75)</sup> one of [The Eight Pre-Hartnell Incarnations](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/02/in-print-episode-68.html)
28. <sup>(42)</sup> [Grandfather Paradox](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2013/11/in-print-episode-60.html)
29. <sup>(76)</sup> one of [The Eight Pre-Hartnell Incarnations](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/02/in-print-episode-68.html)
30. <sup>(77)</sup> [The Curator](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/06/in-print-curation-prelude-ii.html) (as [here](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2017/01/the-dressing-room-part-3-jim-wilkins.html))
31. <sup>(78)</sup> [Valeyard](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/10/in-print-whisper-men.html) sans wig

## Further reading

Now try [this picture](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-B3WdpkRX-CY/Uo0u7Lkv2sI/AAAAAAAACZg/UDwwIeQVe2M/s1600/INPRINTCAST02+copy.jpg).

Comment: I believe Row 2.2 (ghost) is that Fat guy.. Adipose. The first episode of Donna Noble.

Comment: Row 2 #9 is Alpha Centauri. Row 4 #3 is correct, a reference to the novel on which the "Human Nature" was based. I'm not sure on which row you'd put them, but next to the two "Human Nature" Doctors are three members of the Family of Blood (Baines, Farmer Clark, and Lucy Cartwright). Between the Delgado Master and human-McCoy is probably Delgado's Master as he appears in "Survival". What you listed as "WW1 Cyberman" is almost certainly a reference to Brigadier Lethbridge-Stewart, who appears as a Cyberman in "Death in Heaven"

Comment: Also visible "in the back" are [Kandyman](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Kandyman), Dorium's head, the Fourth Doctor (in his burgundy outfit), one of the carnivorous snowmen from "The Snowmen", the unnamed Time Lord general from "Day of the Doctor", and some classic Time Lord who may not be identifiable. Oh, and next to Jack Harness is one of the Movellans from "Destiny of the Daleks". The two guys who look like they're made of chocolate may be the tree people from "The Doctor, the Widow, and the Wardrobe"

Comment: @JasonBaker -- agree with a lot of your IDs.  Also, next to fourth doctor near the back are Jago & Lightfoot (from episode *The Talons of Weng Chiang* and various spin-off stories)

Comment: @Jules Ah, I knew they were familiar; I haven't thought about that episode in ages. Also, the gentleman in the back with the top hat is probably a [Whisper Man](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Whisper_Man). And, just for the sake of completeness, "Mrs. T" is based on [Idris](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Idris) from "The Doctor's Wife" ("Mrs. Tardis")

Comment: Might be a good idea to CW so people can edit. Will also mean everyone above 100 rep can edit it without it having to be cleared by the queues.

Comment: Row 2 #2 is *definitely* an adipose -- it's appeared in the strip the image was taken from.

Comment: The other top-hatted gentleman in the back is probably Doctor Simeon from "The Snowmen" (and/or the Great Intelligence from "The Name of the Doctor"; they're the same character design). Makes sense since he's drawn the same way as Shalka Doctor, and both characters were played by Richard E. Grant. Also, is that [Grimsley from *Santa Claus is Comin' to Town*](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Grimsley) in the back? (for the record I don't think it is, but hot damn if it isn't a striking resemblance)

Comment: I need to check the Ainley Master.  Did he really have vampire fangs?  I'll have a look at the snowmen, tree people, and Weng Chiang characters too.

Comment: @JdeBP Only in his last appearance, in ["Survival"](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Survival_(TV_story)); he was being corrupted by the Cheetah planet. I mentioned it in one of my comments, but I mistakenly said Delgado; but it was indeed Ainley

Comment: I believe Row 6 #4 is meant to be a reference to the 12th Doctor episode "Death in Heaven", which featured a Cyberman that was very heavily implied to be the Brigadier. (I wish I could spoiler a comment as it was one of the most emotional and goose-bump generating moments in the series for me.)

Comment: Back Row #7 is [The Other](http://www.inprintcomic.com/2014/02/in-print-episode-69.html) (one of the founders of the Time Lord society)

Comment: The cloaked figure in front of and between the "cheetaed" Master and the 7th Doctor professor is the 4th Doctor villain from when he went back to Gallifrey.  I think (from memory) that he was the Master's last regeneration looking for a way around the 12 regen limit.

Comment: The dalek is the special weapons dalek from Remembrance.

Comment: I wonder if row 2, #11, labeled as Mrs. T., might not actually be Idris/Sexy/The Tardis from "The Doctor's Wife" ?

Comment: Labelling the War Doctor as the Ninth is just confusing.

Comment: Back row, 7&9 and Jago and Litefoot from Talons of Weng-Chiang

Comment: The War Doctor, despite the name, wasn't an "official" Doctor since he renounced the title.  Eccleston played the Ninth Doctor, not the Tenth Doctor.

Comment: "Mrs T" is Idris/Sexy/"The Doctor's Wife"/human personification of the TARDIS. Jack Harkness is #53. Marvin is #72.

Comment: Just a suggestion.... instead of having tons of comments that will likely be removed or moved to chat, this type of answer is perfect for a community wiki.

Comment: I think 69 is The General from the episode "Hell Bent" and the 50th Anniversary special. I recognised him by his Time Lord armour.

Answer (score 1):

The kids in the back #59 is The Fourth Doctor wax figure that was used for the twentieth anniversary special promo shoot when Tom Baker refused to participate at that time.