# Who is who on this Doctor Who Christmas Card?

Tags: doctor-who, character-identification

When clearing out my desk I found this old Doctor Who Christmas card from my girlfriend.

[image: Christmas card]

I recognise some of the newer Doctor Who characters but others have completely baffled me.

Can anyone help me identify them?

Comment: A similar question is https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173166/ .

Comment: Please please please please upload a flat hi-res version. I would like to print this out for my little son, who loves Doctor Who, as a Christmas card.

Comment: @Sentinel http://alicia-mb.tumblr.com/post/102441804122/a-doctor-who-christmas-party-i-thought-it-would

Comment: Based on the presence of the 12th Doctor but the absence of the 13th Doctor, looks like Christmas 2013 - 2016.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[image]

1. The Third Doctor (Jon Pertwee)
2. Time Lord (probably one of the [Gallifrey High Council](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/High_Council), possibly [Rassilon](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Rassilon))
3. The Fifth Doctor (Peter Davison)
4. Zygon
5. The Sixth Doctor (Colin Baker)
6. 2 Toclafane
7. Davros
8. The First Doctor (William Hartnell)
9. K9
10. The Master (Roger Delgado)
11. Cybermat
12. The Eleventh Doctor (Matt Smith)
13. Jamie (The Empty Child)
14. A Cyberman
15. A Sontaran
16. The Eighth Doctor (Paul McGann)
17. The Seventh Doctor (Sylvester McCoy)
18. The Fourth Doctor (Tom Baker)
19. Adipose (in the 9th Doctor's arms)
20. The Ninth Doctor (Christopher Eccleston)
21. A Weeping Angel
22. The Tenth Doctor (David Tennant)
23. Red Dalek
24. The Twelfth Doctor (Peter Capaldi)
25. A Silence
26. The Second Doctor (Patrick Troughton)

Comment: #2 is probably Rassilon

Answer (score 3):

Front row: The Ninth Doctor holding some Adipose, a Weeping Angel, the Tenth Doctor, a Dalek, the 12th Doctor, a Silent and the Second Doctor.

Second Row: The Master, (with K-9 in behind), the Eleventh Doctor, one of the gas-masked duplicates from "The Empty Child"/"The Doctor Dances", a Cyberman, the Eighth Doctor, a Sontaran dancing in front of him, the Seventh Doctor and the Fourth Doctor.

Third Row: The Third Doctor, a Time Lord, the Fifth Doctor, a Zygon, the Sixth Doctor, Davros, and the First Doctor.